# Trying to stop duplicate values being entered twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

Trying to stop the same value(s) being submitted twice. I have created an function which allows a user to enter a name and a mark to be submitted to a simple site i am trying to create. If the same value(s) (name & mark) are entered I am trying to figure out a way to alert the user and stop the name and mark being submitted to the console.

```js
function add() {
  name.push(nameInput.value);
  mark.push(markInput.value);

  if (name == "" && mark == "") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No name or mark Has Been Entered. Please Try Again!";
  } else if (name && mark) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Name & Mark has successfully been entered!";
    console.log(name, mark);
  } else if (name == mark) {
    var n = name.includes("Ross", 0);
    //console.log(name, mark);//
  }
}

document.getElementById("Add").addEventListener("click", insert);
```

Comment: Excuse the "Enter code here" new to this guys!

Comment: You are pushing values to an array, but the first if statement is checking for a string??? You need to be changing the value, not pushing to an array first thing,.

Comment: Welcome @Ross! Are you saying you want to do something different if and only if the name and the mark have the same value?

Comment: Pretty sure where you pass the function definition to `addEventListener` instead of `insert` you mean to use `add`?

Comment: yeah so i want to to be able to check if the same name and mark has been entered twice, alert the user that they have done so and stop it getting logged to the console.

Comment: function include (){
    document.getElementById("Add").addEventListener("click",function(){
        if (name && mark.includes(""))
    })
}

Comment: I am trying to write a function to check these conditions but I am unsure how to do it based on user Input

Answer (score 0):

You should move  `name.push(nameInput.value);` `mark.push(markInput.value);` into block where it satisfies the  criteria of inserting.Here the criteria is values should not be empty and they should be unique.

```
if (!name  && !mark ) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No name or mark Has Been Entered. Please Try Again!";
  }
else if (names.includes(nameInput.value) && mark.includes(markInput.value)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Name & Mark are same please enter again!";
  }
  else{
      names.push(nameInput.value);
      marks.push(markInput.value);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML ="Name & Mark has successfully been entered!"
  }
```

Alternatively you can also use object to achieve this.
Create an object having the name and mark as properties

```
 let person = {name: name.value,mark: mark.value };
```

and push the object into the `arr`.

To check if the same name and mark are submitted use `arr.find()`.

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name");
let mark = document.getElementById("mark");
let arr = [];
const add = () => {
  if (!name.value || !mark.value) {
    alert("Please enter the value in both fields");
    return;
  }
  let person = {
    name: name.value,
    mark: mark.value
  };
  if (arr.find(personIn => personIn.name == person.name && personIn.mark == person.mark)) {
    alert("Please dont repeat the values");
    return;
  }
  arr.push(person);
}
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', add);
```

```html
Name:<input type="text" id="name" /><br> Mark:
<input type="text" id="mark" /><br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: You didn't find solution?